# InstanceAlreadyExistsException coming from kafka consumer

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am working with Kafka and trying to setup consumer group by follwing this [article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/). The only difference is I have created my own abstract class, handler to make design simpler.

Below is my abstract class:

```
public abstract class Consumer implements Runnable {
  private final Properties consumerProps;
  private final String consumerName;

  public Consumer(String consumerName, Properties consumerProps) {
    this.consumerName = consumerName;
    this.consumerProps = consumerProps;
  }

  protected abstract void shutdown();

  protected abstract void run(String consumerName, Properties consumerProps);

  @Override
  public final void run() {
    run(consumerName, consumerProps);
  }
}
```

Below is my `KafkaConsumerA` which extends above abstract class:

```
public class KafkaConsumerA extends Consumer {
  private KafkaConsumer<byte[], DataHolder> consumer;

  public KafkaConsumerA(String consumerName, Properties consumerProps) {
    super(consumerName, consumerProps);
  }

  @Override
  public void shutdown() {
    consumer.wakeup();
  }

  @Override
  protected void run(String consumerName, Properties consumerProps) {
    // exception comes from below line from two of the threads and the remaining one thread works fine.
    consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps);
    List<String> topics = getTopicsBasisOnConsumerName(consumerName);
    try {
      consumer.subscribe(topics);
      // Setup the schema config
      Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
      config.put("urls", "https://abc.qa.host.com");

      GenericRecordDomainDataDecoder decoder = new GenericRecordDomainDataDecoder(config);
      while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<byte[], DataHolder> records = consumer.poll(200);
        for (ConsumerRecord<byte[], DataHolder> record : records) {
          Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
          data.put("partition", record.partition());
          data.put("offset", record.offset());
          data.put("value", record.value());
          System.out
              .println((Thread.currentThread().getId() % 3) + 1 + ": " + decoder.decode(record.value()));
        }
      }
    } catch (WakeupException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      consumer.close();
    }
  }
}
```

And below is my Handler class:

```
// looks like something is wrong in this class
public final class ConsumerHandler {
  private final ExecutorService executorServiceProcess;
  private final Consumer consumer;
  private final List<Consumer> consumers = new ArrayList<>();

  public ConsumerHandler(Consumer consumer, int poolSize) {
    this.executorServiceProcess = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
    this.consumer = consumer;
    for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; i++) {
      consumers.add(consumer);
      executorServiceProcess.submit(consumer);
    }
  }

  public void shutdown() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        for (Consumer consumer : consumers) {
          consumer.shutdown();
        }
        executorServiceProcess.shutdown();
        try {
          executorServiceProcess.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And here is I am starting all my consumers in the consumer group from the main class:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConsumerHandler handlerA =
        new ConsumerHandler(new KafkaConsumerA("KafkaConsumerA", getConsumerProps()), 3);
    // run KafkaConsumerB here

     handlerA.shutdown();
     // shutdown KafkaConsumerB here
  }
```

So with this - my plan is to setup a consumer group with three consumers in `KafkaConsumerA` and all three subscribed to same topics.

**Error:-**

Whenever I run this, looks like only one consumer in the consumer group works and other two doesn't work. And I see this exception on the console from those two:

```
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: kafka.consumer:type=app-info,id=a97716e0-0e05-4938-8fa1-6b872cf24e34
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser.registerAppInfo(AppInfoParser.java:58) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.0-SASL.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:694) [kafka-clients-0.10.0.0-SASL.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:587) [kafka-clients-0.10.0.0-SASL.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:569) [kafka-clients-0.10.0.0-SASL.jar:na]
```

What is wrong I am doing here? `getConsumerProps()` method return properties object which has `client.id` and `group.id` in it with same value for all three consumers in that consumer group.

**Below is my design details:**

- My `KafkaConsumerA` will have three consumers in a consumer group and each consumer will work on `topicA`.
- My `KafkaConsumerB` (similar to KafkaConsumerA) will have two consumers in a different consumer group and each of those consumer will work on `topicB`.

And these two consumers `KafkaConsumerA` and `KafkaConsumerB` will be running on same box with different consumer group independent of each other.

Answer (score 33):

Kafka is trying to register [MBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) for application monitoring and is using the `client.id` to do so. As you said, you have the properties injected in your abstract class and inject for every consumer the same `client.id` and `group.id` in group `A`. However, you have different clients, so you should give them their own `client.id`, but keep the same `group.id`. This will register the different client/consumers in the same consumer group and make them work together, but not clash on the MBeans registration.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info. I will try it out.. Also do you think my design and logic is right of what I am trying to do. I have mentioned it at the bottom of my question. Or do you see any improvements in design which can be done?

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable setup, but I don't know your domain of course.

Comment: My idea is running multiple kafka consumers on a same JVM. And each kafka consumer will have multiple threads. For example: `KafkaConsumerA` will have three consumer in a consumer group working on `topicA`. `KafkaConsumerB` will have 2 consumer in another consumer group working on `topicB`. And both of these `KafkaConsumerA` and `KafkaConsumerB` will run on a single JVM.

Comment: Sounds perfectly feasible to me.

Comment: ok.. also does this error affects my consumer in that consumer group like it won't receive any data from kafka? Or it is just a warning message telling MBeans registration got failed?

Comment: I _think_ your consumers will still just work, but I would not place a bet on it.

Comment: What's the scope of this group ID ? Is it on the Kafka instance ? I mean if I have consumers on 2 different JVMs with identical group IDs and having identical\duplicate client IDs, will this cause the same warning ?

Answer (score 12):

I understand this is an old question, but given these days we are using annotations alot. So adding another flavour of the problem and answer.
We were facing the same issue, but we had been using @KafkaListener annotation across our 2 consumers in the same app and most of the properties injected directly

```
@KafkaListener(
topics = "${app.source}",
groupId = "${app.kafka.consumer.group-id}",
clientIdPrefix = "subscriber",
containerFactory = ListenerContainerFactory.AVRO_SPECIFIC,
errorHandler = "customConsumerAwareListenerErrorHandler"
)
```

Our consumers were having similar implementation but connected to different topics, so we simply modified the "clientIdPrefix" to give them unique values during instantiation. So the final code was

<-- First Consumer Component ->

```
@KafkaListener(
topics = "${app.source}",
groupId = "${app.kafka.consumer.group-id}",
clientIdPrefix = "firstSubscriber",
containerFactory = ListenerContainerFactory.AVRO_SPECIFIC,
errorHandler = "customConsumerAwareListenerErrorHandler"
)
```

<-- Second Consumer Component ->

```
@KafkaListener(
topics = "${app.source}",
groupId = "${app.kafka.consumer.group-id}",
clientIdPrefix = "secondSubscriber",
containerFactory = ListenerContainerFactory.AVRO_SPECIFIC,
errorHandler = "customConsumerAwareListenerErrorHandler"
)
```

Comment: To make it even more clarified, the `clientIdPrefix` does the job.